# How can I tell what user a VB.Net application is running as and how can I change it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

We have an app that needs to access network resources.  It's written in VB.Net.  The application can't access the files on another server via a UNC path.  How can we find out what user the application is truly running as and how can it be changed?  We tried [this KB from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815171)... but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the logged in user's credentials here is the property to access:

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```

If the app is running in an Application Pool, there is probably some account that it is set up to impersonate for its execution, e.g. local System account, Network Service or other.  Task Manager under Processes can show a User Name for the worker process,e.g. aspnet_wp.exe on XP in IIS 5.1.

If neither of these help, state what version of IIS you are using and what version of VB.Net is being used to help narrow down what is happening.

Comment: Using II6 (w3wp.exe, running at Network Service).  I suppose it is running in the default pool.  I started doing some poking around and now it looks like w3wp.exe is running as the user we are trying to give permissions to... still not able to access the remote path properly, though.

Comment: Are the servers in the same domain?  It may be that Domain1\Network Service isn't the same as Domain2\Network Service.  Also, there are 2 sets of permissions to look at:  Those on the UNC itself in terms of sharing and then those on the files on the server in terms of ACLs.